# How do I change the type of a row in an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

I have an array created from a csv, but the first row contains the title of each column. it has to be a str, but as most of the data is float its now a float64.

The code is the following code that creates the matrix:

```
self.data = np.genfromtxt(self.path, delimiter=",")
```

I need to change the first row to strings but if I use:

```
self.data[0] = self.data[0].astype(str)
```

it returns a row of 'nan's, thing I don't understand.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot have arrays of heterogeneous types in `numpy`.

Comment: Read in as `object` dtype and then set second row onwards to `float` type : `a = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=",", dtype=object)` , `a[1:] = a[1:].astype(float)`?

Comment: If you don't want to use that text line as field (column) names in the array, you can skip it with the `skip_header` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have column names, you can use the `names` argument to pull that out.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=",", names=True)

data

array([( 1.,  4.,  7.), ( 2.,  5.,  8.), ( 3.,  6.,  9.)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8')])
```

You can now do things like `data['a']` to get the array named `'a'`

You can also access the column names with `data.dtype.names` which will return a tuple of all the column names. `('a', 'b', 'c')`

Answer (score 0):

The `np.genfromtxt` function generates an `np.ndarray` by taking your array and casting to the datatype of the array, in this case `float64`.  When you cast this back to a `string`, it has already been cast as a `float64` and so it's read as `NaN`, because presumably your titles are not numbers.

Luckily for you, the function has a way to extract the header.  [By using the "names" parameter:](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) `np.genfromtxt(self.path, delimiter=",", names=True)`, the function will also return a list of column titles from the first line of the input file.

Comment: Thank you, made it much easier with the titles.